# Происхождение слова "солидный"

Tags: этимология

Солидным называют человека значительного, степенного, имеющего некий вес в обществе: "В кабинете сидел солидный пожилой человек в серой тройке". По отношению к вещам или понятиям "солидный" употребляется в значении "большой": "Он получил солидную надбавку к зарплате".
Но интересно, какое у этого слова происхождение? Мне оно кажется родственным слову "солидарность", но, возможно, оно просто созвучно.

Answer (score 3):

Слово *солидный* появилось в русском языке в начале 19 века, в качестве заимствования из французского.

> Солидный
>
> франц. твердый, крепкий, надежный, прочный, вальяжный;
> || солидный человек, основательный, надежный; доброй жизни, не легостай.
>
> Солидарность, круговая порука, один за всех и все за одного;
>
> солидарный, за круговою порукой; к ней, относящийся.
> (Словарь Даля)

Французское слово *solide* восходит к латинскому:

> СОЛИД - (лат . solidus, букв. - прочный, массивный), римская, позднее византийская золотая монета, стала чеканиться в 309. Солид был заимствован у Рима германскими народами и послужил образцом золотых монет раннего средневековья в Зап. Европе.
> (БЭС)

Comment: А как экономика, тут совсем ни при чем? Или невпритям?  солид--откуда?

вся торговля пошла от соли. Потому-то ее корни во всех словах, касающихся торговли, в плоть до sale-продать, и средства достижения рынка сбыта, то есть 
 sail-парус. золото потом,  тоже оттуда. Соли дар естественное желание помочь тому, у кого ее нет, разумеется за малое -- бартер,  а потом, солидарите - читается просто и незамысловато, а потом пошла калька,  ти прибавлять к глаголу.  
 а от туда и порука -- честное купеческое русское слово.
по рукам.

Comment: Немного не **дотянули**. Солид латинский родствен русскому **целковому**. ПИЕ корень ~~~ sol, sal, sel... Целый, здоровый и тп.

Comment: ПИЕ технология это слишком поверхностная, заумная, нелогичная и по большей части не учитывающая причин возникновения того или иного слова метод. Вообще термин неудачный.
Так что соль и ищем причины, почему. У вас есть корень,сел, почему именно в данном корне ЛЕЖИТ смысл. Соль это некоторого рода наркотик, до сих пор на говорят -подсел на наркотик. Животные, найдя где-то соль, с этого места не уходят, соляные выходы на поверхности это типа водопоя.Люди от них ничем не отличаются в этом плане, если не хуже.

Comment: С изменением рациона питания при передвижениях на большие расстояния-миграции из любопытства, чисто человеческое свойство, соль стала носиться и добываться впрок. Стала предметом обмена. Вот так и появилась торговля. А дальше естественные выходы, где сидел народ, быстро истощились, еще один повод для миграции, и  изобретения других способов добычи соли. Там где была соль, появились первые "мено"---полисты -- поселения. СЕЛО. ОСЕДЛОСТЬ.
Приручение животных. Далеко ходить не надо, живность рядом. Охота тоже.

Comment: Соль просто не может лежать кусками на поверхности.  ЕЕ любой дождь смывает.  Только солончаки и могли быть источниками соли. Поэтому слово Целый производная другого порядка.  Так что сначала было СЕЛ,потом была технология и появились обозначения для новых понятий. везде причина порождает следствие.  
А остальные потом + экономика+ география и геология----история.. Без них этимология--звук на пустом месте.

Answer (score 0):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

Solidus (лат) - плотный, массивный, прочный; весь, полный; истинный. Солид, золотая монета.

СОЛИДАРНОСТЬ (по Фасмеру)

солидарный, через нем. solidarisch, франц. solidaire (ХVI в.;  из лат. in solido "в целом".